# Purely functional amortized constant time `decrease-key` for priority queues in Dijkstra?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, priority-queue, dijkstra

Dijkstra's shortest paths algorithm is `O(E log V)` when we re-insert nodes into the priority queue. However, if we use constant-time `decrease_key`, and Fibonacci heap is advertised for this, then the algorithm is `O(V log V)` because the main loop is not entered for every edge, only for every vertex. Is this possible in a purely functional setting? And how -- searching for the node to decrease key is already `O(log n)`? I have found on the internet that 2-3 finger trees can be used to implement amortized `O(1)` `decrease_key`, do Haskell's or OCaml's implementations support it?

Comment: Wikipedia alone knows the "2-3 heap" and the "Brodal queue", have you investigated these? Edit: Turns out the purely functional Brodal queue doesn't have constant time decrease-key, the Brodal & Okasaki paper lists it as future work.

Comment: @delnan I am asking out of curiosity, I have not studied the problem or even read the references yet.

Comment: Before you become too enamored with Fibonacci heaps, you should understand that that O(1) `decrease-key` comes with a fairly large constant. In addition, the simplicity of binary heaps makes the real-world running time faster than F-heaps except with very large data sets. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/508221/56778